# Non-Biased Listing of Party Accomplishments

Tags: voting, parties, history

I was wondering if there is truely any place on the internet where one can see a non-biased list of political party contributions to there respective country (for me specifically Canada)?

I find it quite amazing that regardless of where you go, each given source seems to be quite slanted towards a single party; usually by more then a small ammount as well.

When in a scenerio where you want to actually consider what each given Party has contributed, in say proposed and passed laws and major financial decisions, it seems to me this would be a good starting point to make an intelligent decision on who to back.

Comment: Would you consider **not passing** any new laws an accomplishment?

Comment: Over what kind of a time period?  Frankly, a history book is going t be your best bet.

Comment: Well I was thinking a fairly recent timeframe, say 15 years. I don't think you can really consider a political party to be equal to itself beyond that time period. Also I was hopeing to avoid books out of the sheer convienance of computer information.

Comment: It's a good question, but I'm not sure an answer to is the best way to 'decide which party to back'. Perhaps in part, but there's a lot more to party accomplishments beyond the specific legislation created (which is also often a mash of many different party views--not just one).

Comment: I am pretty sure in any democratic country, including Canada, all laws and list of people voting for them are public. As for if these laws can be considered "contributions" there are many opinions, and none of them is objective since politics is inherently subjective and based on people's beliefs and moral axioms.

Comment: @StasM, "in any democratic country [...] list of people voting for the are public", isn't the case [as evidence in my answer here](http://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/1789/what-other-types-of-votes-are-there-than-roll-call-votes/1791#1791).

Answer (score 5):

For non-biased sources, you could look to the [Congressional Record](http://thomas.loc.gov/home/rollcallvotes.html) in the USA (THOMAS system), and the equivalent Parliament record in Canada ([LEGISinfo](http://www.parl.gc.ca/LegisInfo/Home.aspx?language=E&ParliamentSession=41-1&Page=1)).

Since you are specifically interested in Canada, you can refine your search and only list the bills that meet certain criteria. For example, if you were only interested in [Conservative Party bills from the 41st Parliament, first session, that became law (received Royal Assent)](http://www.parl.gc.ca/LegisInfo/Home.aspx?language=E&ParliamentSession=41-1&BillSponsorAffiliation=Conservative&BillStatus=RoyalAssentGiven&Page=1), you can use the filters on the right to do that.  Similarly, if you were interested in the [Liberal Party](http://www.parl.gc.ca/LegisInfo/Home.aspx?language=E&BillStatus=RoyalAssentGiven&ParliamentSession=37-1&BillSponsorAffiliation=Liberal&Page=1) when they had control of Parliament in 2001, you could do that as well.

Finally, you can access the actual text of the bills by looking them up on [Canada's Justice Laws website](http://www.laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/AnnualStatutes/index2012.html). This resource can be used to ensure that a bill called the 2013 Puppies Protect Act actually protects puppies amd doesn't set up puppy death camps.

Comment: +1 but you should really cover the ground that the comments did, namely that it's frequently wrong or impossible to ascribe party's "accomplishments" to specific passed bills - both because the bills are frequently passed by >1 party votes, and because an accomplishment might be in killing the "bad"-for-the-specific-constituent bill.

Comment: @DVK, since my answer was 19 hours ago, and that comment was 13 hours ago (and not directed at me, so I receive no notification), I will just go back in time and take care of that.

Comment: @User1873 - While you are back here can you deliver a small message to me?